# I am trying to figure out the proper CSS to get this code to work for a Facebook feed on a website

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, facebook

I am using the code below for a Facebook feed I have on a website.  Problem is that it lists the images and the news like it is supposed to but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to put the images on their and have the associated text displayed nicely to the right of it.  Can someone please help.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
//Get the contents of the Facebook page
$FBpage = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/135860723149188/feed?      access_token=456215171075777|OcFg4Sf293Pg3NXeJkg1h3Bg8wE'
);

//Interpret data with JSON
$FBdata = json_decode($FBpage);
//Loop through data for each news item
foreach ($FBdata->data as $news ) {
//Explode News and Page ID's into 2 values
$StatusID = explode("_", $news->id);
echo '<li class="fbframe"; style="list-style:none;" >';
//Check for empty status (for example on shared link only)

if (!empty($news->picture)) {
printf ('<img src="%s" alt="Image from Facebook" />', $news->picture);
}

if (!empty($news->message)) { echo $news->message; }
echo '</li>';
} //end of fbframe
?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help that you can offer.

Comment: You want to discuss a client-side problem (CSS/formatting) – so next time, please accordingly post _client-side_ code, and not server-side code. (Or even better, the URL to a working demo page of your HTML output.)

Answer (score 0):

- wrap the `<li>` elements in an `<ul style="list-style:none;">`
- remove the semi-colon after `"fbframe";`

Comment: ok so I changed it to say '<ul style="list-style:none;"> <li class="fbframe"> then the code stays the same until after the second "if" where the list closes and I have '</li></ul?' but that doesn't do anything more than I already had.  Any suggestions

Comment: Left float the IMGs, add a right-margin to the IMG, set the overflow:hidden on the LI?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Nicole Sullivan's [media object](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/) is exactly what you're looking for, Facebook and all.